# How to redirect to the checkout page after login (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

When users click a purchase button without login, following code opens a login popup (it works well).
My problem is, I need to redirect to the checkout page ([www.mywebsite.com/my-checkout](http://www.mywebsite.com/my-checkout)) after the login (since the user logged in to checkout).
At the moment, when users click the purchase button, it goes to the home page and opens a login popup, and stays on the home page after login.
Would you please let me know how to adjust the following code?

```
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
    function check_if_logged_in()
    {
        $pageid = get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' );
        if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
        {
            $url = add_query_arg(
                'redirect_to',
                get_permalink($pagid),
                site_url('/#login')             
            );
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit;
        }
        if(is_user_logged_in())
        {
            
        if(is_page(get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' )))
        {            
           $redirect = $_GET['redirect_to'];
            if (isset($redirect)) {
            echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$redirect.'";</script>';
            }    
         }
      }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `wp_redirect( $url );` then call `exit;` or `die()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used the code but it doesn't go back to the checkout page. I think this is because, when it redirects the popup login, it autometically goes to the home page, then login page pops up. When a user logged in, it show the home page. Would you please hlep me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_login_redirect` hook.

```
function wc_redirect_login( $redirect, $user ) {

    $redirect_page_id = url_to_postid( $redirect );
    $checkout_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );

    if( $redirect_page_id == $checkout_page_id ) {
        return $redirect;
    }

    return wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_redirect_login' );`
```

You can also try [WooCommerce Login Redirect plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-login-redirect/) to customize redirects.

Comment: HI shahidiqbal: Thank you for your comments. I tried both the code and plugin but it still stays on home page after login. I'm using this plugin for login: Login/Signup Popup ( Inline Form + Woocommerce ). I was wondering if the plugin has something to do with this issue... and if there is a way to solve it...